# Diskpart is not showing all partitions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

I have three partitions as C, D, and E. Below are the sizes for each parition

```
C = 278GB
D = 14GB
E = 5GB
```

Diskpart gives me following output:

```
Parition ##   Type       Size   offset
-----------------------------------------
Partition 1 Dynamic data 922 KB 31 KB
Partition 2 Dynamic data 300 KB 1024 KB
Partition 2 Dynamic data 278 GB 301 MB
Partition 2 Dynamic data 19  GB 279 GB
```

Why it is not showing me D and E separately? I want to make D drive as active drive :( [Because](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/F11-HP-recovery-doesn-t-boot-into-recovery-partition/td-p/197434)

Answer (score 1):

**Your all disks are Dynamic**

Dynamic partition can't be set as Active. please convert them as primary. then set as Active and then you can be

**Updated:**
if you want to convert a disk to basic using diskpart: type this this will help you how to do.
    DISKPART>Convert help
but the problem is you have to delete it.

if you don't want to delete the drive and convert to basic, use this tool
http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.htm

Read About Basic & Dynamic Disk
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How can I convert them without deleting them?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your disk has been converted to a dynamic disk and none of those partitions can be marked as active. "You cannot mark an existing dynamic volume as active. See this article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757696.aspx), specifically the section "Boot and system partitions". If you're still trying to "start fresh" as you indicated in your other thread then I suggest you locate an install disk or request one from your laptop manufacturer. I've seen them send out flash drive installers for systems without optical drives.

Comment: How can I convert them without deleting them?

Comment: You'll have to use a third party utility to do it. There's a guide here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html I've never used it before so I can't vouch for it's reliability.